# Way in asp.net core identity to transfer user credentials to different database without resetting passwords?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm setting up a new database (postgresql) and moving away from MongoDB for my db of choice using asp.net core 2.1 and the built-in identity engine. When I made the switch between the two databases, I'm wondering if there's a way I can simply copy my AspNetUsers and relevant tables over to my postgresql database and not require my users to reset / rehash their passwords?

I ran a few tests between the two systems and the same user with the same password do not appear to have the same password hash even though they are both using asp.net core 2.1. It's not a show-stopper to require users to reset their passwords but I'd really like it to be a seamless process.

I've ran a lot of searches but what I'm coming up with so far is mainly how to transfer from older membership and asp.net systems to the newer identity. Any help / advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how you hashed the passwords in the first place. If you are using some of the inbuilt password hashers of asp.net core Identity, and will continue to use them, then there's no reason that moving a *string* from one db to another will materially make any difference to your code.

Comment: In the old days (SqlMembershipProvider), the hash was tied to the specific machine I believe and you would have to provide the same machinekey for all app instances that would login against the database (and verify the user password hash). This seems not to be the case with Asp.Net Core Identity, where an updated hasher that seems machine/app independent is used(?)

Answer (score 2):

Moving the tokens from one server to another actually worked. It wasn't intuitive at first but they were different tokens when I created a new user on the new server so I'd assumed they wouldn't work, but I guess only part of the token is the password. So even though it's a token generated from another server and it's different than if you'd created the same credentials on the new server, the old token still works if that makes sense.